# Passing multiple value to single variable as function parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameter-passing

I want to pass multiple values as a parameter to a single variable in js. how can I access these value from this variable as the parameter?

---

> the code below is just to show you what I'm trying to achieve.

---

```
function getsum(a,b)
{
   // do something
}

getsum((0,-1),-1);// for now I use parentheses (0,-1).
```

please help how can I pass multiple values?

Comment: Use an array or an object. Don't use the comma operator.

Comment: this is just the module where I just asking how we can pass multiple values to a single variable function parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an array and then access the elements of the array:

```
function getsum(a,b)
{
   // First element
   firstElement = a[0];
   // Second element
   secondElement = a[1];

   // do something
}

getsum([0,-1],-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

use either object or array to acquire this

```js
function getsum(a,b)
{
    console.log("a,b",a,b)
   // do something
}

getsum({val0:0,val1:-1},-1);

function getsum(a,b)
{
    console.log("a,b",a,b)
   // do something
}

getsum([0,-1],-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `(0,-1)` makes use of [the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). It evaluates as `-1`. The `0` never reaches the function.

Use an array or object instead.